# How do you save file on server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, web

I am saving images on file and i am creating first folder which has Guid name for avoiding to duplicate file names. And entities hold reference src of image.

I feel that creating folder and giving guid name is wrong from point of performance. So how i have to avoid duplicate names ?

And second problem is the project seperated into 2 project. One is admin and other for user interface so i can not access my saved files from user interface. What is best practice about these problems ?

Comment: What kind of performance issues are you afraid the GUID-named folder approach will cause?

Comment: You could just store the file on disk using the guid as the filename, maybe with the original extension too, in the same directory and then store the original filename and mime-type in a database. But to avoid having too many files in a directory you might still want to make a directory or directories for the first three or four characters of the GUID, though.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I just guess that giving really long names to folders and creating folder for per photo is not good from point of performance.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you can point if there is no any performance issues about my strategy.

Comment: Any worry about the length of a folder or filename from a performance standpoint is, at best, premature.  Have you actually _measured_ a performance difference?  My initial suspicion is "no."  Implement and then measure, don't just guess.

Answer (score 0):

About the first problem, I think you could create a folder per user and replace the existing file, asking user confermation.
The second problem can be solved using a NFS or a shared directory where the admin and the user application can both read and write files (and you need to develope a component that retrieve the files and return them to your web apps).